# Latency in plugin while recording MIDI

Tags: midi, cubase, plugin, latency

I use Cubase 5, add MIDI track and on this track applied a plugin. I record MIDI from my electronic drums. When the track is recorder and I play it, it is played back OK with no latency at all. But when I want to hear instanly what I am playing on the drums it has latency. Do you have any ideas how to fix this latency?

thank you very much for any ideas, this problem is quite bothering me.

Comment: Hi this seems to be off topic because it's a specific cubase midi problem and not a sound design problem. Have you tried steinberg forums?

Comment: How do you know there is no latency on playback?  If everything has uniform latency, it wouldn't seem like there is latency.

Comment: Is there a headphone-out jack on the electronic drums that you can listen to instead of the output from Cubase?

Comment: yes, there is an output, an the audio from the drums is correct with no latency - it is immediate. And I also dont think it is specifically Cubase problem, it is the same in every DAW I tried. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is just your audio output device that is inducing lag.  On playback, you wouldn't notice the lag as everything would have the same lag.  People are far more sensitive to latency when they are expecting something in reaction to their action than when they are simply hearing something.